# Unable to merge Laravel collections

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-collection

I am not sure why this isn't working. I am having to make a series of paginated calls to an external API and want to combine all the pages into one master collection. Right now each call (page) returns its own collection. I know about the merge() method but for some unknown reason it isn't working.

Here is what I got:

```
$master_collection = collect();

for ($x = 1; $x <= $total_pages; $x++) {
  $page = ApiService::getPage($x); //Returns collection of elements from the requested page
  $master_collection->merge($page);
} 
dd($master_collection);
```

However the dump just returns the empty collection the was initialized but doesn't have any of the page collections merged in. I do know the page collections work fine because I can save `$page` to a new index in an array and `dd()` the array and can see an array of the individual collections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to save the merged collection into the `$master_collection` variable.

```php
$master_collection = collect();

for ($x = 1; $x <= $total_pages; $x++) {
  $page = ApiService::getPage($x); //Returns collection of elements from the requested page
  $master_collection = $master_collection->merge($page);
}
```

Comment: Ah I see, it's creating a new collection with the merge that I have to assign back into the variable instead of just adding the new part to the existing collection. And now it works, thanks.